# How to call another function in the same file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Building a Chrome Extension using Manifest 3. In my `popup.html` I'm including a `popup.js` script as below.

```
goButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });

    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tab.id },
        function: processPage,
    });
});



function determineResult(text) {

    return text;

}


function processPage() {

    var result = determineResult('test'); // UNDEFINED ERROR
    console.log(result);
  
}
```

**Question:** why can't I call `determineResult` from within `processPage`, as it throws a function undefined error?

The only thing that solves this is putting `determineResult` inside the other function but since I would like to reuse it in a couple of places I would like a wider scope.

What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: All functions you call must be within the injected function, not outside. There's no other way.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - that explains! I assume there _must_ be a way to have a "global" function reused across multiple top-level functions other than writing it whole repeatedly inside each of them (which would kind o defeat the purpose of functions). Maybe there's some sort of way to have it as an imported module? Hmm... anyway thanks again!